# How to speed up sqlalchemy filter_by

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have an sqlite DB, which I push data to using sqlalchemy.

I have a couple of classes:

```
class Job(Base):
    __tablename__ = "jobs"

    user_name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("users.user_name"))
    job_id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    base_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column()
    modules: Mapped[list[Module]] = relationship()

    def __init__(
        self,
        job_id: str,

    ) -> None:

        self.job_id = job_id    
        self.base_id = int(re.split("\+|_", self.job_id)[0])


class Module(Base):
    __tablename__ = "modules"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    job_id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("jobs.job_id"))
    module: Mapped[str] = mapped_column()

    def __init__(self, module: str) -> None:

        self.module = module
```

In the Job table there are ~8000000 entries. As part of the package I retrieve job base_ids that need to be processed like:

```
 with Session() as session:
     try:
         jobs_with_none = (
                    session.query(Job.base_id).filter_by(modules=None).all()
                )
         jobs_to_process = [job.base_id for job in jobs_with_none]
     Exception as err:
                self.logger.info(
                    f"Rolling back: Exception thrown in get_jobs_to_process: {' '.join(err.args)}"
                )
```

But it seems to take a very long time (i.e has been hanging no for well over 20 mins). Is there something obvious I am doing wrong here?